# Is there a way to get the ordinality of the array in the JSON using json_normalize or anyother way of doing it in python?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, json-normalize

Is there a way to get the ordinality of the array in the JSON using json_normalize or anyother way of doing it in python ?

I have written the below code to flatten, but I need to add the ordinality, is there a way of doing it simplistic ?

```
import pandas as pd
import json
```

```
json_str = '''{
    "id": "001",
    "Name": "TOM",
"tableData": {
        "subjects": [{
                "Subject": "Maths",
                "alias": "param0"
            }, {
                "Subject": "science",
                "alias": "param1"
                }],
        "marks":[[{
                    "alias": "param0",
                    "value": "85",
                    "Sem" : "first"
                }, {
                    "alias": "param1",
                    "value": "98",
                    "Sem" : "second"
                }       
              ],
              [{
                    "alias": "param0",
                    "value": "88",
                    "Sem" : "first"
                }, {
                    "alias": "param1",
                    "value": "90",
                    "Sem" : "second"
                }       
              ]]
            }  
}'''
dict1 = json.loads(json_str)
dict_subj = pd.json_normalize(dict1,record_path=['tableData','subjects'],meta=['id','Name'])
print(dict_subj)
dict_mark = pd.json_normalize(dict1,record_path=['tableData','marks',[]])
print(dict_mark)
dict_all = pd.merge(dict_subj, dict_mark, on=['alias']) 
print(dict_all)
```

current output:

print(dict_mark)

|  | alias | value | Sem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | param0 | 85 | first |
| 1 | param1 | 98 | second |
| 2 | param0 | 88 | first |
| 3 | param1 | 90 | second |

Needed output :

print(dict_mark)

|  | alias | value | Sem | Ordinality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | param0 | 85 | first | 1 |
| 1 | param1 | 98 | second | 1 |
| 2 | param0 | 88 | first | 2 |
| 3 | param1 | 90 | second | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import json

dict1 = json.loads(json_str)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1['tableData']['marks']).T
df = pd.concat([df[c].apply(pd.Series).assign(Ordinality=i) for i, c in enumerate(df, 1)], ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    alias value     Sem  Ordinality
0  param0    85   first           1
1  param1    98  second           1
2  param0    88   first           2
3  param1    90  second           2
```